# GWT without JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, gwt, graceful-degradation, noscript

I was looking into GWT. It seems nice, but our software have the must work without JS requirement. Is it possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, it isn't. GWT provides a windowing toolkit that is specifically designed to run on the client, not on the server. Degraded (e.g. non-javascript) code would need to deliver complete HTML to the browser, which GWT simply does not do. It compiles your java code to a javascript file that is delivered to the client and builds the UI by DOM-manipulation on the client. Then there's some code to talk back to the server, some implicit, some written by you yourself. This model does not lend itself well to degrading gracefully.

The only way to degrade somewhat gracefully is to provide a second, non-javascript UI or use another toolkit that doesn't render the frontend on the client but delivers HTML. Sorry.

Comment: Fair enough. So GWT, by its nature will only create js files.

Comment: yes - that's it's point. Highly interactive, very impressive. But pure Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

You could degrade gracefully by creating an html structure that is just 'good enough' (with form posts, linked menus, etc) and then have GWT attach to each part of that structure, augmenting its behavior.  For example, make an HTML drop down dynamic, replace a link to another page with a component that opens a lightbox, or replace a link to another page with an XML http request to do the same thing (e.g. cast a vote).

I've done this a number of times for clients.

It's the opposite way that most GWT gets developed, but it can work.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking at this issue myself when designing my website. GWT isn't really any better than just writing Javascript files in that their syntax is almost identical. The true benefit comes when you share client and server libraries. Hopefully you've resolved this issue in the last two years, but at any rate here are a couple examples that you may find useful.

Creating Gmail: With GWT, you can create an EmailFormatter in a shared package that does the email listing markup so that your server doesn't have to. You could then add support for legacy browsers ("older version") by using the same EmailFormatter class on the server side.

Form verification: While is is absolutely necessary from a security perspective to validate user input server side, it is more convenient for most users to have Javascript check a form before it is submitted. You can use the same Java code with GWT to do this.